# Java - establish a chat between two clients

Tags: java, server, chat

Im trying to code a simple server that creates a chat between any two clients that connect to the server. (for any two new clients the server will open a new chat thred/s and then will wait to the next two clients)

i have tried the followןng solution:

Server:

```
public class Server 
{
    public Server() throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(7777);
        Socket s1, s2;
        
        while(true)
        {
            s1 = sc.accept();
            s2 = sc.accept();
            
            new ServerThread(s1, s2).start();
            new ServerThread(s2, s1).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Server threads (two threads as explained in the comment above the class)

```
 /*
  Receives message from sender socket and pass them to the recipient socket
 */
public class ServerThread extends Thread 
{
    Socket sender;
    Socket recipient;
    
    public ServerThread(Socket sender, Socket recipient) 
    {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            handle();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public void handle() throws IOException 
    {
         String msg;
         // Create output stream for the recipient
         OutputStream outputStream = recipient.getOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
         
         // Create input stream for the recipient
         InputStream inputStream = sender.getInputStream();   
         ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
         
         while(true) //sender.isConnected())
         {
             msg = objectInputStream.readUTF();
             
             if(true) //recipient.isConnected())
                 objOutputStream.writeUTF(msg);
             else
                 break;
         }
         
         sender.close();
         recipient.close();
    }
}
```

(Please note that i removed the condotion in the "while" and "if" since i wanted to eliminate anything that will might appear because of it)

Clients main:

```
public class ClientMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        try {
            ClientChat chat = new ClientChat("localhost", 7777);

            //while true gets messages if any and print them to the console
            chat.getMessages(); 
            s = scan.nextLine();
            while(!s.equals("1"))
            {
                chat.sendMessage(s);
                s = scan.nextLine();
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Clients Thread:

```
    public class ClientChat 
    {
    Socket socket;
    String ip;
    int  port;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    
    public ClientChat(String ip, int port)  throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        
         // Create output stream for the recipient
         outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
         objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
         
         // Create input stream for the recipient
         inputStream = socket.getInputStream();   
         objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    }
    
    
    public void getMessages() throws IOException
    {
         
         Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 while(true)//socket.isConnected())
                 {
                     String msg;
                     try {
                        msg = objectInputStream.readUTF();
                         System.out.println(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
            }
         });
         
         t.start();  
    }
    
    
    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        try {
            objOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Well, this code doesn't work,
I have run the server and two clients, the clients do connect to the server, and you can
enter input to readLine() method, but nothing happen.

i have tried to dubug the server, what i found is that it stack on the line:

```
             msg = objectInputStream.readUTF();
```

that all the relevant info i have, if you need some more information please comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#flush()) method from the `ObjectOutputStream` object. If you don't the data to send are stored in an internal buffer. It will get only send when the buffer is full or when you explicit call the `flush()` method.